# Python command target changed

Tags: python, python3, python-2.7

Older versions of Ubuntu shipped with python 2.7 and python 3.6. But in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, only python 3.8 is installed. So when `python` was typed in terminal, python3.8 opened. `python`, `python3` and `python3.8` did the same work of opening python3.8.

But later on when I installed python2.7, it messed the `python` command. When I used `python` command, python2.7 started opening. To use python3.8 now I needed `python3` or `python3.8`.

Can someone explain why did `python` command changed its target application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The policy of the Ubuntu developers, following [PEP394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), is that `python` links ONLY to a Python2 interpreter. Similarly, `python3` links ONLY to a Python3 interpreter.

- You can change `python` to link to anything you wish...but we won't provide support for it.
- No packages in the Ubuntu repositories would link `python` to a Python3 interpreter - any deb package doing so would be an awful bug.

When you install a Python2 interpreter, overwriting your old `python` link (`/usr/bin/python`) with a new link is expected behavior.

Do not install manual files or links in locations commonly used by a package manager (like `/usr/bin`). You can install your own `python` link in several locations in your $PATH that are safe from overwriting by a package manager. For example, `/home` and `/usr/local/`.